# SAPUI5 icon doesn't display

Tags: sapui5

I am using XML views with SAPUI5 and finding that none of my icons are displaying.  Below is some sample code.  The code results in the correct number of tiles and data but no icons.

```
<TileContainer id="caseTiles" height="50%" tiles="{hello>/HelloCollection}">
    <StandardTile id="tileId" press="doIt" icon="sap-icon://hello-world"
        title="{hello>Greeting}"
        info="{hello>Language}"  />
</TileContainer>
```

The same is true everywhere I use icons.  I think I must be missing something but I'm not sure what.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me with the latest UI5 version, see the following [jsbin example](https://output.jsbin.com/minenubihu/edit?html,output). However, I tried with 1.24.3 - 1.26.x and there it does not work. It seems you need at least 1.28.x (i.e. 1.28.4). To test with different versions simply change the bootstrap url from https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js to https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.0/resources/sap-ui-core.js (here you can see what versions are available: [OpenUI5 versionoverview](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html) or [SAPUI5 versionoverview](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html)).

However, I have no idea why I can see the hello-world icon in the demo apps of 1.24.3, see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.24.3/#demoapps.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template by nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

        <!-- template used: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/sapui5-single-file-template-using-xmlviews-controllers-fragments-and-custom-controls-for-bug-illustrations-support-requests-or-demos -->

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                height="100%"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
                <App>
                    <Page 
                        enableScrolling="false" 
                        title="Tile with Icon">
                        <content>
                            <TileContainer>
                                <StandardTile
                                    icon="sap-icon://hello-world"
                                    title="My Title"
                                    info="My Info"/>
                            </TileContainer>
                        </content>
                    </Page>
                </App>
            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because hello-world is not an icon of the SAP font?

Refer to the [Icon Explorer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/iconExplorer.html) for correct names.
[Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/776f7352807e4f82b18176c8fbdc0c56.html) is the walktrough.

Comment: Oddly, hello-world is included in the collection on the SAPUI5 Icon Explorer but I tried a few others to be sure and some of them work (i.e. world and accept) and others don't work (i.e. hello-world and activate).  Could be the collection in the icon explorer isn't up-to-date?

Comment: Hi Ross, can you please give a little more information? Are you using the WEBide? Have you used a template to get started? What version of UI5 are you using?

Comment: I'm using the WDW on premise.  Looks like it's version 1.24.3.

Comment: Hi Ross, 1.24 is pretty outdated. So upgrading that one is always a good idea. Your code should normally be fine.
Perhaps you have not loaded the correct libraries? Try to load sap.m and sap.ui.core. Perhaps you could add some more code to loop through some of the icons to see if they are begin shown. This link might be helpfull: https://jsbin.com/yotoro/edit?html,output